# Conditional Repetitive Custom Fields in Woocommerce Checkout Page are not saved in order_meta

Tags: woocommerce, conditional-statements, customization, checkout

I am having difficulties in saving a series of conditional custom fields in my checkout page: they work on the page, but are not saved in the order_meta. The problem lies certainly in the field name, as these are the same with an increasing number.

Actually in the checkout form the customer ius being asked if he/she travels with a group of persons (i.e. if the order is made for >1 travel package). If the answer is yes (first custom field) then the persons travelling with the customer must be entered (first name, last name, email and phone).

I created thus 4 conditional fields that pass through a "while" cycle with an increasing counter: the counter is also used to define unique field's names as follows.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'travelling_in_group' );

function travelling_in_group( $checkout ) {

    echo '<div id="travelling-in-group"><h3>' . __('Are you paying for a CSR or IDP cruise?') . '</h3>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<p> If you are paying not only for yourself, but also for other people travelling with you, please write in the text below contact details of the persons part of the group</p>';
    echo '<h5>Are you tavelling in group?</h5>';
    woocommerce_form_field( 'travel_group', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('conditional-checkbox form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Yes'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'travel_group' ));


        $quantity_cond = quantity_conditional();
            echo ' <p class="checkout-custom-conditional">Group participants details </p>';
        if ($quantity_cond >1) {
            $i=1;
            while ($i<$quantity_cond) {
                woocommerce_form_field( 'first_name_group_' . $i, array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('form-row-first checkout-custom-conditional'),
                    'placeholder'   => __('First Name'),
                    'label'         => __('First Name'),
                    ), $checkout->get_value( 'first_name_group_'  . $i ));
                woocommerce_form_field( 'last_name_group_'  . $i, array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('form-row-last checkout-custom-conditional'),
                    'placeholder'   => __('Last Name'),
                    'label'         => __('Last Name'),
                    ), $checkout->get_value( 'last_name_group_'  . $i ));
                woocommerce_form_field( 'email_group_'  . $i, array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('form-row-last checkout-custom-conditional'),
                    'placeholder'   => __('Email'),
                    'label'         => __('Email'),
                    ), $checkout->get_value( 'email_group_'  . $i ));
                woocommerce_form_field( 'phone_group_'  . $i, array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'class'         => array('form-row-last checkout-custom-conditional'),
                    'placeholder'   => __('Phone'),
                    'label'         => __('Phone'),
                    ), $checkout->get_value( 'phone_group_'  . $i ));
                $i++;
            }
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
//check for conditional
function quantity_conditional() {
    global $woocommerce;


        foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) { 
            $quantity = $values['quantity'];
            if ($quantity >1)
            {
                $quantity_cart = $quantity;
            }
        }
    return $quantity_cart;
}
```

The code below works fine on the checkout page, but the following code to update the order_meta doesn't work, creating just 4 fields (first name / last name / email / phone) with nothing in it

```
//Update the order meta with field value

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'travelling_in_group_order_meta' );

function travelling_in_group_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['travel_group'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'First Name person_'.$i .'', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['first_name_group_'  . $i] ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Last Name person_'.$i .'', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['last_name_group_'  . $i] ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Email person_'.$i .'', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email_group_'  . $i] ) );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Phone person_'.$i .'', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['phone_group_'  . $i] ) );
    }
}
```

Have you any suggestion on how solve this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Your variable `$i` is not defined in your last function, then you need some more code… And if you have multiple items in cart with different quantities, your quantity_conditional() function will return only the last item quantity…

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec, I was suspecting that. I will work on teh variable $i! Concerning the rest you say, I know, but fortunately the shop is really simple and the situation in which a customer may need to use these new checkout fields will happen only for one single item in multiple quantitiies. We will not have situations with multiple items that  must be dealt through these fields. This is why I didn't bother too much about the quantity_conditional() function!